# How to delpoy drf static files and react app nginx config

Tags: reactjs, nginx, django-rest-framework

I have a simple nginx config. But when I uncomment Django static path for admin react starts return 404 and can't find its main.js files. React serves with `serve -s build` from their docs. Please, help.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_ip;
    
    location / {
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
   }

    #location /static/ {
     #   root /var/www/html;
    #}
    location ~* ^/(api|path/admin) {
       include proxy_params;
       proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;

    }
}
```

Comment: without @AhmadOthman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just having `var/www/html` which is really anything in the root directory because I think that can create conflicts. because nginx is trying to find the `build` folder inside of the `static` folder which is not true.

I think if you copied the `build` folder in the `/static` I think it would work.

I have not really gone through this kind of issue before but I hope it helps.